# get page length on ajax request in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to load page content with ajax and show progress with a progress bar.I use code below but my it can't calculate total page size.

```
xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                $("#loader").css('height', percentComplete * 100 + '%');
                console.log(evt.loaded, evt.total, percentComplete * 100 + '%');
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    }
```

and this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult OurVision(string lan)
    {
        ViewBag.lan = lan;;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting Content-Length response header?

Comment: I don't know how to set content-length Please give me a code or tutorial.